# How to detect whether app is running on browser or mobile app in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have a website that is built with reactJs. I have built a mobile version not using react native but this:

```
import React from "react";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <WebView
      source={{ uri: "https://mywebsiteurl" }}
      style={{ marginTop: 20, backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
    />
  );
}
```

Now I want to detect whether the app is running on a browser or mobile app from inside my web reactJS code.

N.B : I do not want to differentiate between mobile browser and web browser. I want to detect whether browser(any browser of windows/MacOS/ubuntu/IOS/android/Smart tv) or mobile app(IOS/Android)

Comment: Same way you do it for pure js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)

Comment: In my case, it is no comparison between mobile browser and desktop browser. It is the comparison between browser(mobile/desktop/tv) and mobile app(Android/IOS)

Comment: Check this Mozilla doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent#Mobile_Device_Detection

Comment: @EhteshamAhmadNadim you either use react native or some alternative in that case it can be only mobile. Or you use js in that case you should have access to `navigator.userAgent` and [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser) should be enough for you